# Protect the SQLite format 3 to my application only

Tags: c#, sqlite

Database File and Application that reads the db. The application has a registration component added. If the user doesn't want to register they can simply download the open source application, copy the database to the new folder, run a batch file and the database opens in the application, completely eliminating the registration and whatever extra features were added.

I want to keep the database file inhouse, even if it means adding the db file into the resources of the main application. The file does require data to be written to that file.

I've gone as far as converting the batch file to an exe file and loading the database file or even renaming the database file to something obscure like abc.exe (Even though its a db file it can be renamed to anything)

Database file is renamed to an exe file for the time being, I would prefer to either have it encrypted somehow or somehow placed into the resources of my main application and accessed that way, I am just trying to limit the way the software can be pirated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Encryption:
   You can encrypt SQLite databases using extensions such as SQLite Encryption Extension.  The usefulness of such encryption depends on what you are trying to do.  If your application can read the keys to decrypt it, so can a hacker that can run your application.  You can use Windows Data Protection API to manage the keys so that if someone copied the database from one windows machine to another, the database would be unreadable; but again, if the hacker can access the source machine, they can obtain the keys just like your application (but it would protect against a "dumb" user from just copying the files over).
2. Putting it in your "main application resources":  If you mean embedding the database within the EXE, you are out of luck if you have a requirement to write the data.  Generally speaking, an EXE cannot modify itself (though depending on OS/version/user permission/absense of antimalware agents, etc, you might theoretically accomplish a self-modifying EXE; but, if you want your app to *work* most of the time in the wild, this strategy won't succeed).  Even if you did succeed in an EXE that read itself, loaded the embedded blob as a database, modified that database in memory, then rewrote the entire EXE with database exported as a new blob (of different size than the original, wreaking havoc on the assembly), it wouldn't help.  The attacker can do what your app does and access the data.  Do yourself a favor and follow the operating system's guidelines for writing user data.  For Windows, this is generally reading and writing files to your Local App Data folder.
3. Renaming a SQLite database to have an `EXE` extension.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Obscurity?  Renaming it to `EXE` might fool some users (certainly not the motivated user I've described above), but it also might accidentally fool anti-malware / anti-virus software running on your legitimate user's operating systems into thinking your application is writing malformed executables (which would be suspicious) and shut your application down, or at least prevent it from working correctly.  This will cause your users to not use your application or a mountain of support for you.  What does it gain?  It stops a "dumb" user from trying to open it in a SQLite query tool?

All that said, if you want to limit your user's abilities to read the data stored on their own storage devices, you really can't stop a determined user.  You can stop the less savvy users.  The majority of users cannot run a reflector on a C# assembly and figure out what it is doing, but many can.   If you want to stop the less savvy users, encryption of the data will stop most of them, and it will be the least likely approach you've discussed to prevent your application from working "in the wild".

Comment: Which is why I introduced obfuscation into my C#, when I use reflector its a pile of mess :)